# Is it possible to wrap a docker image, and do works before and after it's origin operations?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to use `sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli` as a kubernetes container, so I do this in a yaml:

```
- name: "sonarqube-scan-{{ .Values.git.commitID }}"
  image: "{{ .Values.harbor.host }}/{{ .Values.harbor.cache }}/sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli"
  env:
    # Sonarqube's URL
    - name: SONAR_HOST_URL
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: sonarqube
          key: sonar-url
    # Auth token of sonarqube's bot
    - name: SONAR_LOGIN
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: sonar-bot
          key: sonar-token
  volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /usr/src
      name: initrepo
```

Now, I want to do some pre-setup before the `sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cl` regular run and parse the docker container's run output for some other works. If this is a shell script, I do like:

```
$before.sh
$sonar-scanner-cl.sh | after.sh
```

I guess I can build a new docker image which is `FROM sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cl`, and put processes in `before.sh` and `after.sh` in its run script, but I don't know how to call the original `sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cl` run commands. What are the actual commands?

Or, alternatively, does kubernetes have a way to do this?

Comment: you can modify the `command` arguments in the yaml spec to run multiple comments. what is the current command btw? You can also look at `initContainers` as an option.

Comment: There's no current command. I'll take a look about `initContainers`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how one can modify container commands without building another image.

1. Pull the image

```sh
docker pull sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli
```

2. Inspect it

```sh
docker inspect sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli
```

You should get something like this:

```json
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "CMD [\"sonar-scanner\"]" <- arguments
            ],
            "WorkingDir": "/usr/src",
            "Entrypoint": [ <- executable
                "/usr/bin/entrypoint.sh"
            ],
```

`Entrypoint` is *what* will be executed and `CMD [...]` (not `Cmd`) are the arguments for the executable. In a human-friendly format that equals to:

```sh
#      entrypoint          args
/usr/bin/entrypoint.sh sonar-scanner
```

Now in this case we have a script that is being executed so there are two options.

#### Option 1: Modify the entrypoint script and mount it at launch

1. Run this to save the script on your machine:

```sh
docker run --rm --entrypoint="" sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli /bin/cat /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh > entrypoint.sh
```

2. Modify `entrypoint.sh` as you like, then put its contents into a configMap.
3. Mount the file from the configMap instead of /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh (don't forget to set mode to `0755`)

#### Option 2: Change entrypoint and arguments in resource definition

Note that this may not work with some images (ones with no shell inside).

```yaml
- name: "sonarqube-scan-{{ .Values.git.commitID }}"
  image: "{{ .Values.harbor.host }}/{{ .Values.harbor.cache }}/sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli"
  command: # this is entrypoint in k8s API
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
  args:  # this goes instead of CMD
    - "before.sh && /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh sonar-scanner && after.sh"
                 # | original command and args          |
```